# How to test that an intent has been broadcasted

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am broadcasting an intent when a "record" button is clicked. a boolean variable is passed, that shows whether the recording is started or not. The code to generate an intent is:

```
Intent recordIntent = new Intent(ACTION_RECORDING_STATUS_CHANGED);
recordIntent.putExtra(RECORDING_STARTED, getIsRecordingStarted());
sendBroadcast(recordIntent);
```

To test this code I have registered a receiver in test. The intent is received but the variable passed is not the same. If I debug the code, I can see that the value is same as it is sent, but when I get it, its not the same value.

```
@Test
public void pressingRecordButtonOnceGenerateStartRecordingIntent()
        throws Exception {
    // Assign
    AppActivity activity = new AppActivity();
    activity.onCreate(null);
    activity.onResume();

    activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            // Assert
            ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(intent);
            assertThat(shadowIntent
                    .hasExtra(AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED),
                    equalTo(true));
            Boolean expected = true;
            Boolean actual = shadowIntent.getExtras().getBoolean(
                    AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED, false);
            assertThat(actual, equalTo(expected));

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(
            AppActivity.ACTION_RECORDING_STATUS_CHANGED));

    ImageButton recordButton = (ImageButton) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);

    // Act
    recordButton.performClick();
    ShadowHandler.idleMainLooper();

}
```

I have also tested against the actual intent instead of its shadow, but same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the get() instead of getBoolean() worked for me.

```
public void pressingRecordButtonOnceGenerateStartRecordingIntent()
        throws Exception {
    // Assign
    BreathAnalyzerAppActivity activity = new AppActivity();
    activity.onCreate(null);
    activity.onResume();

    activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            // Assert
            assertThat(intent
                    .hasExtra(AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED),
                    equalTo(true));
            Boolean expected = true;
            Boolean actual = (Boolean)intent.getExtras().get(
                    AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED);
            assertThat(actual, equalTo(expected));


        }
    }, new IntentFilter(
            AppActivity.ACTION_RECORDING_STATUS_CHANGED));

    ImageButton recordButton = (ImageButton) activity
            .findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);

    // Act
    recordButton.performClick();
    ShadowHandler.idleMainLooper();

}
```

Comment: Do any of the `assert`s in the `BroadcastReceiver` actually get called? I tried both `assertThat(intent.hasExtra(AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED), equalTo(true));` and `assertThat(intent.hasExtra(AppActivity.RECORDING_STARTED), equalTo(false));` and my tests did not fail in both cases. So, my guess is that those assert statements never actually get called.

Comment: No, it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

in Robolectri

```
shadowOf(ApplicationProvider.<Application>getApplicationContext()).getBroadcastIntents();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not help for the original, but, future people: if you happen to find yourself in this situation - firstly check your constants and intent filters are distinct so that an unintentional broadcast is not received by your receiver. Several times I've spent longer than I care to admit with that issue!